# Has Anyone Actually Created a System that Writes Computer Programs from specification?

Tags: logic, type-theory, coq, proof-assistants

Has anyone ever actually written a system (software or detailed explanation on paper with simple examples) that generates computer programs?  I input $Prime(x) \wedge x<10$ and it creates a program that lists the prime numbers less than 10.  $Prime(x)$ is simply defined as 
$$1<x \wedge \not\exists A\; s.t. 1<A \wedge A<x \wedge x=A\times B,\mbox{ with }
A,B\in \mathbb{N}$$
Professors say they can but nobody gives actual complete examples.

Comment: You mean like, you know, a compiler for a general purpose programming language?

Comment: Hi - welcome to cstheory!  Unfortunately your question is not a research level question in theoretical computer science and is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Actually, this is a good question, at the top of current research, and
very promising. However, it is often very hard to specify precisely
what you want.  If you manage to specify it, then you need a system
that will prove that it makes sense, that it is feasible, and that will
require a mathematical proof. From that proof a program doing it can
be extracted. But research for automating the proof and the program
extraction is still in infancy, though making nice progress. You may
look for example at [**Coq**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq) on wikipedia.- - - cc @LevReyzin

Comment: What does 'arbitrary' mean here?

Comment: Here is a [book](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717106800076) corresponding to your question. There are others. It is **not** simple to understand. The Coq and Isabelle (another such system) crowd does include SE users who could give you more information and examples if the question were not closed.  I found it by searching the web for: coq example program synthesis.

Comment: Wolfram in ANKS had some interesting musings on writing a compiler that targeted Diophantine equations. Matiyasevich proved they were universal, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_tenth_problem

Seen any actual implementation of this? I bet once your program is compiled to a set of Diophantine equations you could do a lot of interesting analysis.

Comment: The area of computer science that captures what I you're asking about is called [program synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_synthesis) and is an active area of research.

Comment: some overlap also with [automatic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming). there is use of SAT encoding somewhat for this purpose (eg encoding the factoring problem in SAT or other math problems).

Comment: @SashoNikolov I believe your witty comment is either trivial or
wrong. The question asks for writing a program from specification. The
word *specification* remains unprecise: it could be specification of
what is to be done, what output should be obtained from what input for
example, or a specification of a way to achieve some result:
specification of what or how.  Despite some exception, compilers start
mostly from a how spec, i.e. a program, to be translated into another
one. The issue usually intended is to specify with a
predicate what is to be achieved, not how it can be.

Comment: @babou You are right, of course. It's a silly comment, and I doubt I meant it as more than a silly comment, not that I remember what I was thinking three years ago.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I expected that you meant it as a joke, and probably thought as much 3
years ago. I was only bothered that it was much supported, wondering
whether supporters understood it as a joke. The good point is that it
forced me to realize that we easily forget that the word specification
alone is somewhat ambiguous for many people.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very active research topic, very promising, though full
automation of program generation probably has intrinsic limitations (but are human beings any better?).
But the idea is still be very useful in assisting considerably the
creation of programs by mechanizing many steps, and by automatically
checking the correctness of the program generation.

It is strongly related to a result in logic, called the [Curry-Howard
correspondance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) (or isomorphism), that shows that computer programs and
mathematical proofs are very similar.

So the idea is that the system will take your program specification as a
theorem to be proved. In the case of your example, it would be
something like (informally): "there is a set of all prime numbers smaller
than 10".

Then, you will attempt to prove that theorem, and existing systems
will assist you in doing the proof, automating some parts, possibly the whole proof, and making
sure you never make errors.

From that proof one can then extract a program
that actually computes the  wanted list of prime numbers that had been
initially specified.

Several systems were developed in the past to elucidate these ideas. One
of the better known was [LCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_for_Computable_Functions) by [Robin Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Milner), who created the language
[ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_programming_language) for that purpose. One of the currently most advanced systems is
[Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq).

There are examples fully worked out, some of them quite complex. You may find some in the following [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717106800076), though it is in no way simple reading and requires advanced knowledge of Logic.

Answer (score 9):

The wag answer: Yes, but at the time of writing, for most nontrivial programs the specifications seem to be just as hard to write and debug as the programs would be.

More seriously, babou's answer is good, but I'm also going to suggest checking out the area of dependent types. There's [a rather good book using Coq](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) (full disclaimer: written by a friend of mine), but there's also Epigram, Agda, and Idris. Isabelle/HOL is also worth checking out.

These are all based on the calculus of constructions. If you want to know the theoretical basis, look up Martin-Löf type theory. There are some great introductions around.

Comment: I fully agree regarding specifications (and also the rest of your
answer, but you know it better than I do). Any real programmer knows
how difficult it is to fully specify what a program should do. It is a
major issue in software engineering. And that translates also here,
even though the problems addressed are more mathematical in general.
However, I did not want to sound too discouraging (especially given
the history of this question, illustrated by the first comment).

Answer (score 4):

Going off in a tangent here, program generators (i.e., systems that given a high-level description of something in some special language) have been around forever. Any compiler is one of those, as is any of the many parser generators. Back in the day systems called "third generation languages," which generated (most of the) code of a typical business application given a high-level description and a catalog of available data were popular.

Answer (score 1):

[Logic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming) and, more generally, [Declarative Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) take as a premise exactly what you propose: namely, from a logical specification, return a result fulfilling that specification.

One area which seems to specifically address the "primes less than 10" example you give is [Constraint Programing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) which tries to find solutions to problems involving certain constraints, including integer constraints like those you gave.

You might want to try [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/index.html) for a specific (open source) implementation of such a system.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that the logic/constraint paradigm is more to specify answers than to specify programs. Of course, you might say that an incomplete specification is a program. But somehow, I am not sure it is the same game as program synthesis. It is true though that it does answer the example, because the example was very simple. I do not mean to say that constraints programming is only for simple problems.